# Expect script to iterate through list of files, fetch file and perform local file manipulation

Tags: tcl, expect

I have been struggling with this problem now for a few days.

The task would be to connect to an sftp server, iterate through a list of files to
1. Fetch the file from sftp
2. Perform some file manipulation locally, then go to next file in the list.

This would be my minimal example:

```
set filelist_path filelist.txt

proc slurp {file} {
    set fh [open $file r]
    set ret [read $fh]
    close $fh
    return $ret
}

set filelist [slurp $filelist_path]
set rundir [file normalize [file dirname .]]

### Start connection to ftp server
spawn sftp ${user}@${host}
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\r"

### Download and manipulate files in the list


foreach item $filelist {
    expect "sftp>"
    send_user "Processing $item : \n"
    set filedir [file dirname ${item}]
    set outdir ${rundir}/tmp${filedir}
    puts [exec mkdir -p $outdir]
    send "lcd $outdir \r"
    send "get -p /data'${item}'\r"
    send "lcd $rundir \r"
    puts [exec <some cmd>]
    puts [exec rm -r ./tmp]
}

send "quit\r"
expect eof
```

My problem is, that local manipulation is never performed or iteration does not wait for the manipulation to finish.
I have tried playing with the 'expect "sftp>"' order and put some 'interact' statements to see what is going on, but with no success.

Comment: Expect is very timing sensitive. after you `send` something you need to `expect` something. just like when you manually interact with `sftp`: you input some cmd, wait for it to complete and you see next `sftp> ` prompt and then you input next cmd, ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't waiting for the commands you `send` to finish before processing the file. It takes *time* to move a file, even a small one. The easiest way is to `expect "sftp>"` *after* each command you `send`, even the trivial ones. It's how you verify that the other program has finished what it was doing.

And move the initial one out of the loop; think of it as being part of connection setup.

---

I'd be inclined to write a procedure to send a command and wait for it to finish. That could then also check for error cases in a systematic way (and `expect` gives you the tools to do so). Errors are where programming gets more complicated, after all...